# java application occupying almost cpu time 100%

Tags: java

i am running one java program(server and client),where server reads the file data and send to client

I am not getting what is the problem it is using almost more cpu

My top command output:

```
top - 02:56:54 up 31 days,  3:29,  0 users,  load average: 9.94, 10.24, 10.69
Tasks: 382 total,   1 running, 381 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.6%us,  1.2%sy,  0.9%ni, 97.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16334088k total, 16110308k used,   223780k free,  2143596k buffers
Swap:  8388600k total,    37632k used,  8350968k free,  1704888k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
14383 wladmin   20   0 5673m 546m 3912 S 789.5  3.4 963:51.08 java              
 9790 wladmin   20   0  9.9g 4.7g 6112 S  3.9 30.2  53:06.77 java               
29970 wladmin   20   0 15152 1396  860 R  2.0  0.0   0:00.01 top                
    1 root      20   0 19360 1220  988 S  0.0  0.0   0:03.43 init
```

and here are my Thread Dumps

```
14383:

===== FULL THREAD DUMP ===============
Fri Nov  1 03:24:42 2013
Oracle JRockit(R) R28.2.5-20-152429-1.6.0_37-20120927-1915-linux-x86_64

"Main Thread" id=1 idx=0x4 tid=14385 prio=5 alive, in native
    at sun/nio/ch/ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;[Ljava/net/InetSocketAddress;)I(Native Method)
    at sun/nio/ch/ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:150)
    ^-- Holding lock: java/lang/Object@0xf1960150[biased lock]
    at CavMonAgent.Listener(CavMonAgent.java:349)
    at CavMonAgent.main(CavMonAgent.java:388)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"(Signal Handler)" id=2 idx=0x8 tid=14386 prio=5 alive, native_blocked, daemon

"(OC Main Thread)" id=3 idx=0xc tid=14387 prio=5 alive, native_waiting, daemon

"(GC Worker Thread 1)" id=? idx=0x10 tid=14388 prio=5 alive, daemon

"(GC Worker Thread 2)" id=? idx=0x14 tid=14389 prio=5 alive, daemon

"(GC Worker Thread 3)" id=? idx=0x18 tid=14390 prio=5 alive, daemon

"(GC Worker Thread 4)" id=? idx=0x1c tid=14391 prio=5 alive, daemon

"(GC Worker Thread 5)" id=? idx=0x20 tid=14392 prio=5 alive, daemon

"(GC Worker Thread 6)" id=? idx=0x24 tid=14393 prio=5 alive, daemon

"(GC Worker Thread 7)" id=? idx=0x28 tid=14394 prio=5 alive, daemon

"(GC Worker Thread 8)" id=? idx=0x2c tid=14395 prio=5 alive, daemon

"(Code Generation Thread 1)" id=4 idx=0x30 tid=14396 prio=5 alive, native_waiting, daemon

"(Code Optimization Thread 1)" id=5 idx=0x34 tid=14397 prio=5 alive, native_waiting, daemon

"(VM Periodic Task)" id=6 idx=0x38 tid=14398 prio=10 alive, native_blocked, daemon

"Finalizer" id=7 idx=0x3c tid=14399 prio=8 alive, native_waiting, daemon
    at jrockit/memory/Finalizer.waitForFinalizees(J[Ljava/lang/Object;)I(Native Method)
    at jrockit/memory/Finalizer.access$700(Finalizer.java:12)
    at jrockit/memory/Finalizer$4.run(Finalizer.java:189)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"Reference Handler" id=8 idx=0x40 tid=14400 prio=10 alive, native_waiting, daemon
    at java/lang/ref/Reference.waitForActivatedQueue(J)Ljava/lang/ref/Reference;(Native Method)
    at java/lang/ref/Reference.access$100(Reference.java:11)
    at java/lang/ref/Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:82)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"(Sensor Event Thread)" id=9 idx=0x44 tid=14401 prio=5 alive, native_blocked, daemon

"VM JFR Buffer Thread" id=10 idx=0x48 tid=14402 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon

"TestRunMgr" id=11 idx=0x4c tid=14405 prio=5 alive, sleeping, native_waiting
    at java/lang/Thread.sleep(J)V(Native Method)
    at TestRunMgr.run(TestRunMgr.java:358)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=930 idx=0x50 tid=1867 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=932 idx=0x54 tid=1881 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=935 idx=0x5c tid=1886 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=933 idx=0x60 tid=1883 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=938 idx=0x64 tid=1890 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=937 idx=0x68 tid=1888 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=939 idx=0x6c tid=1891 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=934 idx=0x70 tid=1885 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"JavaMonitorAsThread" id=895 idx=0x80 tid=1791 prio=5 alive, sleeping, native_waiting
    at java/lang/Thread.sleep(J)V(Native Method)
    at cm_java_gc_ex.runOnce(cm_java_gc_ex.java:1024)
    at cm_java_gc_ex.startMonitor(cm_java_gc_ex.java:1061)
    at Server.procMsgFromNetstorm(Server.java:619)
    at Server.tcpRecv(Server.java:465)
    at Server.run(Server.java:292)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"SendFile" id=999 idx=0x90 tid=23590 prio=5 alive, native_blocked
    at sun/nio/ch/SocketDispatcher.read1(Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;[BII)I(Native Method)
    at sun/nio/ch/SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:46)[optimized]
    at sun/nio/ch/IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:255)[inlined]
    at sun/nio/ch/SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:245)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: java/lang/Object@0xf35b2058[thin lock]
    at sun/nio/ch/SocketAdaptor$SocketInputStream.read(SocketAdaptor.java:184)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: java/lang/Object@0xf35b2040[thin lock]
    at sun/nio/ch/ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:86)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: sun/nio/ch/SocketAdaptor$SocketInputStream@0xf35b2190[biased lock]
    at sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)[optimized]
    at sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)[optimized]
    at sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)[inlined]
    at java/io/InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: java/io/InputStreamReader@0xf35b4730[recursive]
    at java/io/BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)[optimized]
    at java/io/BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)[inlined]
    at java/io/BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: java/io/InputStreamReader@0xf35b4730[biased lock]
    at ServerSendFile.runOnce(ServerSendFile.java:645)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.startSendFile(ServerSendFile.java:216)[optimized]
    at Server.procMsgFromNetstorm(Server.java:583)[optimized]
    at Server.tcpRecv(Server.java:465)
    at Server.run(Server.java:292)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"SendFile" id=989 idx=0x98 tid=14552 prio=5 alive, native_blocked
    at java/io/RandomAccessFile.length()J(Native Method)
    at ServerSendFile.getAndSetDataFromFile(ServerSendFile.java:783)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.runOnce(ServerSendFile.java:639)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.startSendFile(ServerSendFile.java:216)[optimized]
    at Server.procMsgFromNetstorm(Server.java:583)
    at Server.tcpRecv(Server.java:465)
    at Server.run(Server.java:292)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"SendFile" id=993 idx=0xa0 tid=18369 prio=5 alive, native_blocked
    at java/io/RandomAccessFile.length()J(Native Method)
    at ServerSendFile.getAndSetDataFromFile(ServerSendFile.java:783)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.runOnce(ServerSendFile.java:639)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.startSendFile(ServerSendFile.java:216)[optimized]
    at Server.procMsgFromNetstorm(Server.java:583)[optimized]
    at Server.tcpRecv(Server.java:465)
    at Server.run(Server.java:292)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"SendFile" id=985 idx=0xb8 tid=10666 prio=5 alive, native_blocked
    at sun/nio/ch/SocketDispatcher.read1(Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;[BII)I(Native Method)
    at sun/nio/ch/SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:46)[optimized]
    at sun/nio/ch/IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:255)[inlined]
    at sun/nio/ch/SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:245)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: java/lang/Object@0xf20844a8[thin lock]
    at sun/nio/ch/SocketAdaptor$SocketInputStream.read(SocketAdaptor.java:184)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: java/lang/Object@0xf20844a0[thin lock]
    at sun/nio/ch/ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:86)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: sun/nio/ch/SocketAdaptor$SocketInputStream@0xf2084528[biased lock]
    at sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)[optimized]
    at sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)[optimized]
    at sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)[inlined]
    at java/io/InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: java/io/InputStreamReader@0xf20865b0[recursive]
    at java/io/BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)[optimized]
    at java/io/BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)[inlined]
    at java/io/BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: java/io/InputStreamReader@0xf20865b0[biased lock]
    at ServerSendFile.runOnce(ServerSendFile.java:645)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.startSendFile(ServerSendFile.java:216)
    at Server.procMsgFromNetstorm(Server.java:583)
    at Server.tcpRecv(Server.java:465)
    at Server.run(Server.java:292)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"SendFile" id=1003 idx=0xc4 tid=27190 prio=5 alive, in native
    at sun/nio/ch/EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(JIJI)I(Native Method)
    at sun/nio/ch/EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:210)[inlined]
    at sun/nio/ch/EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:65)[inlined]
    at sun/nio/ch/SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:69)[inlined]
    at sun/nio/ch/SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:80)[inlined]
    at sun/nio/ch/SocketAdaptor$SocketInputStream.read(SocketAdaptor.java:193)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: sun/nio/ch/Util$2@0xf2d38250[biased lock]
    ^-- Holding lock: java/util/Collections$UnmodifiableSet@0xf2d38240[biased lock]
    ^-- Holding lock: sun/nio/ch/EPollSelectorImpl@0xf2d36170[biased lock]
    ^-- Holding lock: java/lang/Object@0xf2d36078[thin lock]
    at sun/nio/ch/ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:86)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: sun/nio/ch/SocketAdaptor$SocketInputStream@0xf2d36150[biased lock]
    at sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)[optimized]
    at sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)[optimized]
    at sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)[inlined]
    at java/io/InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: java/io/InputStreamReader@0xf2d38818[recursive]
    at java/io/BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)[optimized]
    at java/io/BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)[inlined]
    at java/io/BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: java/io/InputStreamReader@0xf2d38818[biased lock]
    at ServerSendFile.runOnce(ServerSendFile.java:645)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.startSendFile(ServerSendFile.java:216)[optimized]
    at Server.procMsgFromNetstorm(Server.java:583)[optimized]
    at Server.tcpRecv(Server.java:465)
    at Server.run(Server.java:292)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"SendFile" id=990 idx=0x124 tid=14553 prio=5 alive, native_blocked
    at java/io/UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Ljava/io/File;)I(Native Method)
    at java/io/UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:228)[inlined]
    at java/io/File.exists(File.java:733)[inlined]
    at monitor/common/CmonUtils.isTestOver(CmonUtils.java:210)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.runOnce(ServerSendFile.java:622)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.startSendFile(ServerSendFile.java:216)[optimized]
    at Server.procMsgFromNetstorm(Server.java:583)
    at Server.tcpRecv(Server.java:465)
    at Server.run(Server.java:292)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"SendFile" id=994 idx=0x130 tid=18370 prio=5 alive, native_blocked
    at java/io/RandomAccessFile.length()J(Native Method)
    at ServerSendFile.getAndSetDataFromFile(ServerSendFile.java:783)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.runOnce(ServerSendFile.java:639)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.startSendFile(ServerSendFile.java:216)[optimized]
    at Server.procMsgFromNetstorm(Server.java:583)[optimized]
    at Server.tcpRecv(Server.java:465)
    at Server.run(Server.java:292)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"SendFile" id=998 idx=0x134 tid=23589 prio=5 alive, native_blocked
    at java/io/RandomAccessFile.length()J(Native Method)
    at ServerSendFile.getAndSetDataFromFile(ServerSendFile.java:783)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.runOnce(ServerSendFile.java:639)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.startSendFile(ServerSendFile.java:216)[optimized]
    at Server.procMsgFromNetstorm(Server.java:583)[optimized]
    at Server.tcpRecv(Server.java:465)
    at Server.run(Server.java:292)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"SendFile" id=1002 idx=0x140 tid=27188 prio=5 alive, in native
    at sun/nio/ch/EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(JIJI)I(Native Method)
    at sun/nio/ch/EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:210)[inlined]
    at sun/nio/ch/EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:65)[inlined]
    at sun/nio/ch/SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:69)[inlined]
    at sun/nio/ch/SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:80)[inlined]
    at sun/nio/ch/SocketAdaptor$SocketInputStream.read(SocketAdaptor.java:193)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: sun/nio/ch/Util$2@0xf2d480b0[biased lock]
    ^-- Holding lock: java/util/Collections$UnmodifiableSet@0xf2d480a0[biased lock]
    ^-- Holding lock: sun/nio/ch/EPollSelectorImpl@0xf2d48010[biased lock]
    ^-- Holding lock: java/lang/Object@0xf2d483f0[thin lock]
    at sun/nio/ch/ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:86)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: sun/nio/ch/SocketAdaptor$SocketInputStream@0xf2d48478[biased lock]
    at sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)[optimized]
    at sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)[optimized]
    at sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)[inlined]
    at java/io/InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: java/io/InputStreamReader@0xf2d487f8[recursive]
    at java/io/BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)[optimized]
    at java/io/BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)[inlined]
    at java/io/BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)[optimized]
    ^-- Holding lock: java/io/InputStreamReader@0xf2d487f8[biased lock]
    at ServerSendFile.runOnce(ServerSendFile.java:645)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.startSendFile(ServerSendFile.java:216)[optimized]
    at Server.procMsgFromNetstorm(Server.java:583)[optimized]
    at Server.tcpRecv(Server.java:465)
    at Server.run(Server.java:292)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=941 idx=0x170 tid=1893 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"SendFile" id=986 idx=0x178 tid=10667 prio=5 alive, native_blocked
    at java/io/RandomAccessFile.length()J(Native Method)
    at ServerSendFile.getAndSetDataFromFile(ServerSendFile.java:783)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.runOnce(ServerSendFile.java:639)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.startSendFile(ServerSendFile.java:216)
    at Server.procMsgFromNetstorm(Server.java:583)
    at Server.tcpRecv(Server.java:465)
    at Server.run(Server.java:292)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=945 idx=0x184 tid=1897 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=936 idx=0x188 tid=1887 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=942 idx=0x18c tid=1894 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=947 idx=0x190 tid=1902 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=952 idx=0x194 tid=1908 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=954 idx=0x198 tid=1912 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=943 idx=0x19c tid=1895 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=940 idx=0x1a0 tid=1892 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=948 idx=0x1a4 tid=1903 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=949 idx=0x1a8 tid=1904 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=953 idx=0x1ac tid=1910 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=946 idx=0x1b0 tid=1898 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=951 idx=0x1b4 tid=1906 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=950 idx=0x1b8 tid=1905 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=944 idx=0x1bc tid=1896 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=955 idx=0x1c0 tid=1960 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=956 idx=0x1c4 tid=2147 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=957 idx=0x1c8 tid=2269 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=959 idx=0x1d0 tid=3297 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"SendFile" id=960 idx=0x1d4 tid=3298 prio=5 alive, native_blocked
    at java/io/RandomAccessFile.length()J(Native Method)
    at ServerSendFile.getAndSetDataFromFile(ServerSendFile.java:783)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.runOnce(ServerSendFile.java:639)
    at ServerSendFile.startSendFile(ServerSendFile.java:216)
    at Server.procMsgFromNetstorm(Server.java:583)
    at Server.tcpRecv(Server.java:465)
    at Server.run(Server.java:292)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"process reaper" id=961 idx=0x1d8 tid=3300 prio=5 alive, in native, daemon
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(I)I(Native Method)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess.access$900(UNIXProcess.java:20)
    at java/lang/UNIXProcess$1$1.run(UNIXProcess.java:132)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"SendFile" id=962 idx=0x1dc tid=3512 prio=5 alive, native_blocked
    at java/io/RandomAccessFile.length()J(Native Method)
    at ServerSendFile.getAndSetDataFromFile(ServerSendFile.java:783)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.runOnce(ServerSendFile.java:639)
    at ServerSendFile.startSendFile(ServerSendFile.java:216)
    at Server.procMsgFromNetstorm(Server.java:583)
    at Server.tcpRecv(Server.java:465)
    at Server.run(Server.java:292)
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"SendFile" id=1114 idx=0x284 tid=19816 prio=5 alive, native_blocked
    at java/io/RandomAccessFile.length()J(Native Method)
    at ServerSendFile.getAndSetDataFromFile(ServerSendFile.java:783)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.runOnce(ServerSendFile.java:639)[optimized]
    at ServerSendFile.startSendFile(ServerSendFile.java:216)[optimized]
    at Server.procMsgFromNetstorm(Server.java:583)[optimized]
    at Server.tcpRecv(Server.java:465)[optimized]
    at Server.run(Server.java:292)[optimized]
    at java/lang/Thread.run(Thread.java:662)[optimized]
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

===== END OF THREAD DUMP ===============
```

Why it is consuming this much CPU utilization

Comment: Attach with VisualVM (or the equivalent for JRockit) and tell it to profile your code.  Also note that the _load average_ being high does not mean that there is a lot to do.  See that you have `97.2% idle`.

Comment: show the code at server side accept and client side connection pls. Isn't there an infinite loop or something?

Comment: how is your server managing the sessions? did you develop that managment, let it to jetty or other container? Executor.createXXX ?

Comment: You can also use `htop` to find out thread which eats all the CPU.

Comment: I'm wondering about all those `process reaper` threads. That indicates that your Java process starts many other processes and then waits for them to terminate.

Comment: I see you have 16GB of main memory and that you use 3.4% for you program, so 550MB. Could it be that you have set this upper limit when running your java code? I mean -Xmx550m? I have had the same problem of cpu usage when I was consuming all allowed memory.